# How to set variable value inside read file function and use it outside in node js?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to read the file content as string and want to set the variable value equals to it. But when I try to access `file_data` variable in this case, this gives an empty value if it's used outside the function. However inside the `fs.readFile` function, it works fine.

```
var fs = require('fs');

let file_data = '';

fs.readFile('text_file.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data); //this works fine here
    file_data = data; //setting it here so that I can use it afterwards
});

//the following line gives blank output
console.log(file_data );
```

I'm a bit new at this, so please point out if there is something I need to read first before using functions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fs.readFile() is an async function so

```
//the following line gives blank output
console.log(file_data );
```

Is processed before fs.readFile() responds, so you can:

```
fs.readFile('text_file.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data); //this works fine here
    file_data = data; //setting it here so that I can use it afterwards

    // CONSOLE LOG HERE!! AND IT WORKS
    console.log(file_data );

});
```

Alternatively, you can use the synchronous version fs.readFileSync()

```
try {
  const data = fs.readFileSync('text_file.txt', 'utf8')
  console.log(data)
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

[Source](https://nodejs.dev/learn/reading-files-with-nodejs)

Comment: Really appreciate the answer. I think synchronous version of it suits well with my particular case. Thanks a lot.